# ArcPy - Strip leading and trailing blank spaces from records in table

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a feature class in ArcMap which for many rows in numerous fields has records with leading and/or trailing blanks spaces.

I want to remove iterate through the fields and rows and remove any leading or trailing blanks spaces using 'strip'.

I have had a go a writing this in python below (using ArcMap 10.3.1)

```py
FC = r"C:\Data\Survey.shp"
AllFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FC)]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, AllFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
         row.strip()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant apply strip to all field types, only type string/text. So you need to specify only these. For example like this:

```
fieldlist=['Field1','Field2']
```

Or if you want to apply to all text fields you can do:

```
fieldlist=[i.name for i in arcpy.ListFields(FC) if i.type=='String']
```

And then the UpdateCursor including updateRow which updates the current row in the table:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC,fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row=[i.strip() if i is not None else None for i in row]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want your list comprehension to be [i.strip() if i != None else None for i in row]. This will prevent errors being thrown due to null values.